# how can i structure a query which dynamically assigns an entity to a customer on sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the data in the following format

```
entities    Customer    Area_code   Marketshareofcustomer   sales($)
1               A           xy              20%             1000
2               B           xy              30%             1000
3               C           xy              10%             1000
4               D           xy              40%             1000
5                           xy                              1000
6                           xy                              1000
7               G           ab              60%             1000
8               E           ab              40%             1000
9                           ab                              1000
```

and the desired result is as

```
Area_Code   Customer    Sales
xy              A       1400
xy              B       1600
xy              C       1200
xy              D       1800
ab              G       1600
ab              E       1400
```

how can i structure my sql statement

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Reading your data I can't undestand how you go from 1000 to 1400, 1600, 1200. Please explain your formula.

Comment: the sales of entities which are not mapped to customer(5,6,9) and are mapped to a area code(xy,ab) will be split among the existing customers in the area. i,e the entity 9 is mapped to area ab so its sales(1000) will be split among customers in that area (G,E) proportional to their market share(60,40). hence G gets a revenue if 1000+.6*1000=1600 . Same goes for E.

Comment: Please next time also add that information to your question by editing. There you can format the text and make it easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

- First you calculate the sales without mapped customer (empty_sales)
- Then join that result and split by share

Take note I include aditional column to make it clear:

- s_sales: Share sales, the column you want
- m_sales: Market Sales. Sales with mapped customers
- e_sales: Total Empty Sales

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/1b94a/9)

```
WITH empty_share AS (
    SELECT area_code, SUM ( sales ) sales
    FROM market
    WHERE customer is null
    GROUP BY area_code
)
SELECT 
     m.area_code, 
     m.customer, 
     m.sales + e.sales * m.market_share s_sales, 
     m.sales m_sales, 
     e.sales e_sales
FROM 
    market m inner join
    empty_share e 
       ON m.area_code = e.area_code
WHERE m.customer IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Well was is easy when you explain the complete problem. Please consider accept this answer and upvote when you have privileges.